# how to include verticale dot between two equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

i want to include verticale dot between two equations like in the picture below

[image]

here is the code i used for the equations

```
\[
  \tilde{\pi}_{t}-\theta \tilde{\pi}}_{t-1}
= \frac{(1-\zeta\beta)(1-\zeta)}{\zeta}\left(\widetilde{mc}_{t}+\tilde{v_{t}}\right)+\beta \left(E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{t+1}-\theta\tilde{\pi}}_{t}\right)
\]
 \[\Leftrightarrow\]
 \[\Leftrightarrow\]
 \[\tilde{\pi}}_{t}
= \frac{\theta}{1+\beta\theta}\tilde{\pi}_{t-1}+\frac{\beta {1+\beta\theta}E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{t+1}+\frac{(1-\zeta\beta)(1 \zeta) {\zeta(1+\beta\theta)}\left(\widetilde{mc}_{t}+\tilde{v_{t}}\right)
\]
```

Comment: There is a macro `\vdots`.

Comment: i want the dot between the Leftrightarrow

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Please don't post incorrect code in your questions. Post the code that you actually used (copy and paste).

Answer (score 6):

Here is something that works: (Note: I had to correct your code).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 &  \tilde{\pi}_{t}-\theta \tilde{\pi}_{t-1}
=\frac{(1-\zeta\beta)(1-\zeta)}{\zeta}\left(\widetilde{mc}_{t}+\tilde{v_{t}}\right)+\beta \left(E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{t+1}-\theta\tilde{\pi}_{t}\right)\\
 & {}\Leftrightarrow\\
 & \ \vdots \\
 & \Leftrightarrow\\
 & \tilde{\pi}_{t}
=\frac{\theta}{1+\beta\theta}\tilde{\pi}_{t-1}+\frac{\beta}{1+\beta\theta}E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{t+1}+\frac{(1-\zeta\beta)(1- \zeta)} {\zeta(1+\beta\theta)}\left(\widetilde{mc}_{t}+\tilde{v_{t}}\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`mathtools` has a macro for this, but it makes some assumptions that are not valid here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vdotsin}[1]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\displaystyle#1$}%
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{$\m@th\displaystyle\vdots$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]% just to see the equations in context
\begin{align*}
&  \tilde{\pi}_{t}-\theta \tilde{\pi}_{t-1} = 
   \frac{(1-\zeta\beta)(1-\zeta)}{\zeta}
     (\widetilde{mc}_{t}+\tilde{v}_{t})+
   \beta (E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{t+1}-\theta\tilde{\pi}_{t}) \\
&  {\Leftrightarrow} \\
&  \vdotsin{\Leftrightarrow} \\
&  {\Leftrightarrow} \\
&  \tilde{\pi}_{t} = 
   \frac{\theta}{1+\beta\theta}\tilde{\pi}_{t-1}+
  \frac{\beta}{1+\beta\theta}E_{t}\tilde{\pi}_{t+1}+
  \frac{(1-\zeta\beta)(1-\zeta)}{\zeta(1+\beta\theta)}(\widetilde{mc}_{t}+\tilde{v}_{t})
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3] % just to see the equation in context

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few points to note:

1. Never ever put two consecutive displayed equations; `amsmath` provides plenty of resources for complex alignments.
2. Avoid `\left` and `\right` when they're not necessary (which doesn't happen often); in your code they weren't.
3. Be consistent with the tilde: you were using both `\tilde{\pi}_{t}` and `\tilde{v_{t}}`; it's the first always or, if you want the tilde to cover also the subscript, `\widetilde{v_{t}}`.
4. In this particular case where the alignment is at the left, `\Leftrightarrow` must be braced, or it would be shifted to the right.

Comment: that's genius ,Thank you for clarifying this